# PyQt does not run with error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I made virtual environment with anaconda and install the pyqt library
and then wrote some code in pycharm:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel("Hello PyQt")
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

I run the code with my virtual envs and then I get the error message:

```
PyQt does not run with error: This application failed to start because no Qt 
platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this 
problem
```

I tried to fix this and someone told me that add system environment variable
so I added it

variable name: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH
variable value: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36_32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms

but it did not fix the problem and error message changed:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
Qt platform plugin "windows" in
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36_32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
```

and I also recongnized that there is no such directory C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py36_32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5 exist but there is no Qt folder in PyQt5

Comment: Do you have also opencv in the same env? Once i got the same error and i found out it was related to conflicts with opencv: indeed opencv comes with some qt5 plugins. I solved by deleting the qt plugin folder inside Opencv package (from site-packages/opencv...)

Comment: I deleted it but it did not work I guess maybe there is some conflicts so I totally deleted anaconda3 and reinstall and it works